# How can I compute a large complex value efficiently in MATLAB, Python, andC?

Tags: python, c, matlab, complex-numbers, gpib

I am facing a problem during my work with MATLAB, to compute `sinh(a + b * i)` (e.g., `1000+1i`), where `i` is the imaginary unit and `a`, `b` are quite large values that type double" cannot handle. Surely I can compute the function via Wolfram or Fortran, but I do need a common language to do the [GPIB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE-488) communication together with this calculation.

After asking this to some guys, I was told Python or C has a type called "big float". But none of them can tell me what is the precision nor the max value of it, not to mention the efficiency. So can anyone suggest a solution? Or maybe there's another language can handle this problem (compute large complex and GPIB session).

Comment: How big is "quite large"?  What precision do you require?

Comment: Also, the `sinh` function grows way, way faster than its input, right?  I don't know about how it behaves in the complex plane, but what are you doing with the result?  What is the upper bound of the output, and are you planning to do something with that which might be translated away by careful application of trig identities?

Comment: I need to run a 10,000 iteration loop with at least 300 by 300 complex value matrix, during the iterations, sinh(z) will increase somehow. From current debug log, z value is 785.4 + 0.178 i at interation 8,400

Comment: And, my formula is like "sinh(z)/sinh(z/2)*sqrt(c+shin(z)/c+sinh(z/2))", where c is a real constant

Comment: sinh(z)/sinh(z/2)*sqrt((c+shin(z))/(c+sinh(z/2)))

Comment: What has high precision numbers to do with GPIB communication? Why are more than 14 significant figures necessary?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Julia](https://julialang.org/):

```
julia> a = BigFloat("1e10")
1.0e+10

julia> b = BigFloat("1e500")
1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004e+500

julia> sinh(a + b * im)
1.43445592092543814302692567115470616209662482064997303227590320999972133381932e+4342944818 + 5.194323395284352151694584377260055302504830707661913916785283453158333278974902e+4342944818im
```

but as others have commented, and as you can see in this example, `sinh` grows quickly with the real part of your complex number, so you can't have too big a `a`. (With `a = 1e10`, the result already reached `10^4342944818` !)

FWIW, in Julia, written down as an integer, the biggest `BigFloat` would have about 1,388,255,822,130,839,282 digits:

```
julia> prevfloat(typemax(BigFloat))
5.875653789111587590936911998878442589938516392745498308333779606469323584389875e+1388255822130839282
```

Also, I don't know how accurate this result is.

Comment: Many thanks, Julia is a powerful numerical tool. And it seems working on my problem. Btw, does Julia support GPIB? Or do I need to seperate the GPIB part and calculation part?

Comment: Not sure, but you could check https://github.com/BBN-Q/Instruments.jl for example